# ChildView in the last of RelativeLayout cannot see when API>20

Tags: android, overlay, android-relativelayout

**Here is my code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<Button
    android:text="button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    />
<TextView
    android:text="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

when API>20,TextView was cover by the button,how to fix it?if the first child is a TextView,it does not happen.Does it a bug in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have root layout match_parent in height and width 
**you are occupying complete space by button with android:layout_height=match_parent**

and for textview you are not using reference of button to place over the layout Relative layout provides  **android:layout_below** attribute you can use this for placing your textview below button

check below example will give you more details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:text="button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        />
    <TextView
        android:text="right"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**To Highlight :** This is not bug in android you are not using it in proper way

Comment: if i want a view Located in the upper right corner of another,how to realize it?

Comment: Add screenshot how do you want ?

Comment: my reputation is lower than 10,so i cannot upload the picture.if you copy my code in layout folder and choose the preview api lower than 21,you will get it

Comment: I am not finding any change in layout with APis i have checked it.Read explanation.

Comment: That‘s strange！In my Android Studio 2.1.2 is different.Well, I finally solved it by replace the Button Widget of A TextView.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <Button
            android:text="button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_right"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_right"
            android:text="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is not the result i want.i want the textview Located in the upper right corner of the button.my code works well below api20